# Schedule a job on success of other in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I want to Schedule to run **ETL_Job2**  no Success of **ETL_Job1** and on Success of ETL_Job2 has to start **ETL_Job3**.

Jobs are to be created in the SQL Server Agent and the SSIS packages associated with the respective job are from the separate solutions.

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is, you can maintain a table and at the end of the entire package process, the Execute SQL Task in SSIS Package should update the status of it. (Make sure that Error Handling should be done for that and in case of error it should update failure.)

And on another hand, another job should trigger itself to check the status of that table, once it gets status successful it can be started. All checking you can do in SSIS Package.

Comment: Yes, I now have a table tracking the status of the package.
Status
1  for Success
2  Failed
3  In Progress

Now, how do I create and run  ETL_Job2 when PackageStatus=1  in the table?

Comment: first of all, retrieve status from source, and compare using Expression Task or using providing Constraint by double click on a link that connects a source and further process.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to make a job run based on the success of another job.

The usual way to do this is to make all three "jobs" be different steps in the same job.